# Get rows that do not have a value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I think that this code would work with a few modifications, but I'm not sure how to reference the table and column names, or how to compare the values.

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
  WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

I have two tables, Groups and Users. Groups is a list of all available groups like this:

```
| group  | mission       |
| test   | just testing  |
| design | still testing |
| rand   | last one      |
```

Users is a list of users:

```
| user   | group  |
| me     | test   |
| me     | rand   |
| you    | test   |
| you    | design |
```

Only one user will be queried at a time. If the query was run on user "me", it should just return with:

```
| group  |
| design |
```

So I'm thinking it would be something like:

```
select group from groups where username = "me" and ....
```

and that's where I get lost.

Comment: `where b.id is null and a.user='me'`?

Comment: Google and learn about `SQL JOINS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first guess is almost correct:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eca9b/3

```
SELECT g.*
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN users u
 ON u.group = g.group
    AND u.user = 'me'
WHERE u.user IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question because it's not very clear, but based on the title I would imagine you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.User NOT IN (SELECT user FROM Table2)
```